# Ошибка после установки на чистую систему

Tags: linux, ubuntu

После установки Ubuntu LTS 20.04.4 вылезает ошибка: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110), которая не дает загрузится в систему. Устанавливал на ноутбук Asus tuf gaming (2022). Подскажите, что можно сделать для ее решения.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225934/ucsi-acpi-ppm-init-failed-110

Comment: установка драйвера не помогает

Comment: Попробуйте при установке выбрать минимальныю установку без установки драйверов. У меня с DELL такая шляпа была. Драйвера потом поставил.

Comment: Вот так случилось что давно хотел погонять кеды на своем TUF (в феврале брал) кубунта зашла как дети в школу.

Comment: кубунта может и зайдет, лтска убунты даже минимальная не ставится, только что проверил

Comment: запустил в режиме nomodeset, посоветуете что делать дальше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбрал минимальную установку, после чего запустил через nomodeset, затем установил проприетарные драйвера nvidia, перезагрузил и теперь все работает!